# Save un-scaled canvas with image background after changes were applied

Tags: html, image, canvas, editor

I've got a big issue and it's almost a week trying to make it work so any help I would really appreciate - I am trying to create a simple image editor in html5, so I upload an image, load it into canvas and then paint on it -

I also want to be able to zoom in and zoom out- just that I can't figure out how should I save the canvas state - for the paint mouseevents I am using an array which saves canvas.toDataUrl, but this one will save only what it is visible in canvas, only a part of the scaled image, and not the entire one -

if anyone knows how can I un-scale the canvas together with the painting over it and save it in the stack from where I can retrieve it for other painting events, I'll appreciate a lot! Thanks

Comment: A bit more info please :)  Do you want to change the pixels of the image itself or do you want to apply annotations on top of the image (lines, text, etc)?

Comment: Hello, I want to draw lines, like a paint brush, and also I am applying distortions (image warp). Just that after zooming in the canvas, and applying all the editors, if I want to save the state, then it will not save the un-scaled final image, only a part of the image currently visible in canvas- because the image is getting bigger than the width and height of the canvas, and using dataURL, will get only what's visible...Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Saving state

The canvas' `save()` and `restore()` is not related to the pixels in the canvas at all. `Save()` only saves current pen color, fill color, transform, scale, rotation and so forth - parameter values only, not actual pixel data.

And so, the `restore()` will only restore these parameter values to the previous ones.

The canvas element is passive, meaning it only holds the pixels that you see on the screen. It does not keep a backup of anything so if you change its size, re-size browser window or open dialogs in the browser causing it to clear, you will need to update the canvas yourself.

This also applies when you change a parameter value such as scale. Nothing on the canvas will change setting a new value. The only thing that happens is that your *next* draw of what-ever will use these parameter values for the drawing (in other words: if you apply rotation nothing rotates, but the next thing you draw will be rotated).

### Drawing on existing image

As you need to maintain the content it also means you need to store the image you draw on as well as what you draw.

When you draw for example lines you need to record every stroke to arrays. When the canvas needs an update (ie. zoom) you redraw the original image first at the new scale, then iterate through the arrays with lines and re-render them too.

Same for points, rectangles, circles and what have you..

Think of canvas as just a snapshot of what you have stored elsewhere (image object, arrays, objects) . Canvas is just a view-port for that data.

I would recommend to store as this:

```
var backgroundImage;  //reference to your uploaded image

var renderStack = []; //stores all drawing objects (see below)

//example generic object to hold strokes, shapes etc.
function renderObject() {
    this.type = 'stroke';  //or rectangle, or circle, or dot, ...
    this.x1;
    this.y1;
    this.x2;
    this.y2;
    this.radius;
    this.penWidth;
    this.penColor;
    this.fillColor;
    this.points = [];
    //...  extend as you need or use separate object for each type
}
```

When you then draw a stroke (pseudo):

```
var currentRenderObject;

function mouseDown(e) {

    //get a new render object for new shape/line etc.
    currentRenderObject = new renderObject();

     //get type from your selected tool
    currentRenderObject.type = 'stroke'; //for example

    //do the normal draw operations, mouse position etc.
    x =..., y = ...
}

function mouseMove(e) {

    //get mouse positions, draw as normal
    x = ..., y = ...

    //store the points to the array, here:
    //we have a line or stroke, so we push the
    //values to ourpoint-array in the renderObject
    currentRenderObject.points.push(x);
    currentRenderObject.points.push(y);

}
function mouseUp(e) {

    //when paint is done, push the current renderObject
    //to our render stack
    renderStack.push(currentRenderObject);
}
```

Now you can make a redraw function:

```
function redraw() {

    clearCanvas();

    drawBackgroundImage();

    for(var i = 0, ro; ro = renderStack[i]; i++) {

        switch(ro.type) {
            case 'stroke':
                //... parse through point list
                break;
            case 'rectangle':
                //... draw rectangle
                break;
            ...
        }
    } 
}

function zoom(factor) {
    //set new zoom, position (scale/translate if you don't
    //want to do it manually). Remember that mouse coords need
    //to be recalculated as well to match the zoom factor.

    redraw();
}

//when canvas is scaled for some reason, or the window
canvas.onresize = windows.onresize = redraw;
```

A bonus doing this here is you can use your render stack as a undo/redo stack as well...

Hope this helped to better understand how canvas works.

Comment: Thank you for your time, it helped a lot, I will improve my solution I've implemented after many hours of reading about transformations with what you've pointed out.